# SQL: Tree structure without parent key

Tags: sql, sqlite, tree

Note: The Data schema can not be changed. I'm stuck with it.

Database: SQLite

I have a simple tree structure, `without parent keys`, that is only 1 level deep. I have simplied the data for clarity:

```
ID    Content       Title
1     Null          Canada
2     25            Toronto
3     33            Vancouver
4     Null          USA
5     45            New York
6     56            Dallas
```

The structure is ordinal as well so all Canadian Cities are > Canada's ID of 1 and less than the USA's ID of 4

Question: How do I select all a nation's Cities when I do not know how many there are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tbl
 where id > 1
   and id < (select min(id) from tbl where content is null and id > 1)
```

EDIT

I just realized the above does not work if there are no countries with greater ID. This should fix it.

```
select * from tbl a
 where id > 4
   and id < (select coalesce(b.id,a.id+1) from tbl b where b.content is null and b.id > a.id)
```

Edit 2 - Also made subquery fully correlated, so only have to change country id in one place.

Answer (score 2):

My query assigns every city to every country, which is probably not what you want, but:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/94d63/3

```
SELECT *

FROM (
      SELECT
        place.Title AS country_name,
        place.ID AS id,

        (SELECT MIN(ID)
         FROM place AS next_place
         WHERE next_place.ID > place.ID
           AND next_place.Content IS NULL
        ) AS next_id

      FROM place
      WHERE place.Content IS NULL
     ) AS country

INNER JOIN place
 ON place.ID > country.id
AND CASE WHEN country.next_id IS NOT NULL
         THEN place.ID < country.next_id
         ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have here severals things to consider, one is if your data is gonna change and the other one is if it isn't gonna change, for the first one exist 2 solutions, and for the second, just one.

- If your data is organize as shown in your example, you can do a select top 3, i.e.

  `SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM CITIES)`
- You can create another table where you specify wich city belongs to what parent, and make the hierarchy by yourself.

I reccomend the second one to be used.